# Twitter Profile Picture URL Canvas, resulting in image not appearing when saving HTML as PNG. How do I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, twitter

So I am developing a basic application that allows people to input a Tweet link, which then my app displays a customizable React component of that Tweet, where they can ultimately "export" (save) that customized component as either a PNG or SVG. The customization works perfectly, but the issue comes in when the HTML is converted to an image format using [`html-to-image`](https://github.com/bubkoo/html-to-image). My UI component, which looks like: [image: UI component] ends up getting saved without the profile picture, and the alt text appears instead like so: [image: Saved HTML converted to image with alt text showing in place of the PFP.]

The way my application works is from my front end, after the user inputs a Tweet link, I call a serverless (edge) function that is deployed on `vercel` with the request body containing the `status_id` of the Tweet (the ID for the Tweet). My serverless function has all of the Twitter API credentials and makes a request to the Twitter API with the provided `status_id`, gathers the response, and responds back to my front-end with something that looks like:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "text": "I recently had a chance to check out some of the latest devices and experiences in augmented reality. It was a lot of fun to see how far the hardware has come. <stackoverflow_doesnt_permit_short_links>",
        "entities": {
            "urls": [
                {
                    "start": 160,
                    "end": 183,
                    "url": "<url_omitted_because_StackOverflow_doesnt_permit_it>",
                    "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/BillGates/status/1513270642900017154/photo/1",
                    "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/vfZfALQuXV"
                }
            ]
        },
        "id": "1513270642900017154",
        "author_id": "50393960",
        "public_metrics": {
            "retweet_count": 204,
            "reply_count": 0,
            "like_count": 2121,
            "quote_count": 74
        },
        "possibly_sensitive": false,
        "created_at": "2022-04-10T21:40:11.000Z"
    }
],
"includes": {
    "users": [
        {
            "profile_image_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1414439092373254147/JdS8yLGI_normal.jpg",
            "id": "50393960",
            "verified": true,
            "username": "BillGates",
            "name": "Bill Gates"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Ultimately, the `profile_image_url` value is converted from the link ending in `_normal.jpg` to the exact same link ending in `_bigger.jpg`, so that the image is large enough to be displayed in my Tweet component. This URL is used as the `src` attribute (passed as a prop) to my Tweet component. What I think is happening here is that the image is "tainting" the canvas, and as a result, the `html-to-image` library that I am using is unable to "see" it when rendering the HTML to a `<canvas>`. I am not super familiar with how CORS or this "Same-origin" policy works, and I am asking for help as to how I can mitigate this. Do I just need to perhaps locally store the image when I receive it back from the serverless function? That way the image is cached locally instead of having to be rendered from Twitter.com?

The code that makes the call to my API looks like:

```
fetch(twitter_api_endpoint, req)
      .then((resp: Response) => {
        // Resolve the JSON promise
        resp
          .json()
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            let tweetData: TweetData = data.data[0];
            let includedUserData: TweetIncludes = data.includes.users[0];
            console.log(
              `TweetData: ${JSON.stringify(
                tweetData
              )}\nIncludes: ${JSON.stringify(includedUserData)}.`
            );

            let snippetState: ISnippet = {
              name: includedUserData.name,
              handle: `@${includedUserData.username}`,
              verified: includedUserData.verified,
              pfp_link: getFullSizePfpLink(
                includedUserData.profile_image_url
              ),
              tweet_body: tweetData.text,
              timestamp: new Date(tweetData.created_at),
              replies: prettifyTweetMetric(
                tweetData.public_metrics.reply_count
              ),
              retweets: prettifyTweetMetric(
                tweetData.public_metrics.retweet_count
              ),
              likes: prettifyTweetMetric(tweetData.public_metrics.like_count),
            };

            if (tweetData.entities) {
              if (tweetData.entities.urls)
                snippetState.tweet_urls = tweetData.entities.urls;
              if (tweetData.entities.hashtags)
                snippetState.tweet_hashtags = tweetData.entities.hashtags;
              if (tweetData.entities.mentions)
                snippetState.tweet_mentions = tweetData.entities.mentions;
            }

            setTweetComponentProps(snippetState);
          })
          .catch((err: Error) => {
            console.log(
              `There was an error resolving the JSON returned by the API.\n${err}`
            );
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

I have ran into information talking about potentially using a proxy to mitigate this, but I have no experience with proxies. If anyone has any resources they could point me to to better explain this, I would be grateful.